# Must specify a {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}type attribute value for the {http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata}metadata element

Tags: community, salesforce1-app, salesforce-id

I'm trying to update CustomField using Salesforce Metadata API version WSDL 39.0 and 46.0
When I try to update CustomField namely InlineHelpText it updates in **Dev Org** correctly without any exceptions.
But for test, we use **Scratch Org** and so I try to update CustomField namely InlineHelpText it fails and returns exception like :

```
 javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Must specify a {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}type attribute value for the {http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata}metadata element
              at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:160)
              at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy98.updateMetadata(Unknown Source)
              at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor47.invoke(Unknown Source)
              at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
              at com.projects.sfdc.util.SfdcWebserviceUtil$SfdcWebserviceMethodInterceptor.invokeInterceptedMethod(SfdcWebserviceUtil.java:569)
              at com.projects.sfdc.util.SfdcWebserviceUtil$SfdcWebserviceMethodInterceptor.invoke(SfdcWebserviceUtil.java:546)
              at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
              at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy99.updateMetadata(Unknown Source)
              at com.projects.sfdc.util.SfdcMetadataUtil.lambda$updateCustomField$23(SfdcMetadataUtil.java:660)
              at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
              at com.projects.sfdc.util.SfdcMetadataUtil.updateCustomField(SfdcMetadataUtil.java:660)
              at com.projects.sfdc.util.SfdcRemoteUpgradeCommandLineUtil.changeUIHelpTextOnMinSupportCustomField(SfdcRemoteUpgradeCommandLineUtil.java:537)
              at com.projects.sfdc.util.SfdcRemoteUpgradeCommandLineUtil.runRemoteUpgrade(SfdcRemoteUpgradeCommandLineUtil.java:376)
              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The methods that I use for both Orgs to update CustomField :

```
public void updateCustomField(List<CustomField> customField)
{
    List<Metadata> collect = customField.stream().map(co -> (Metadata) co).collect(Collectors.toList());
    getSfdcWebserviceUtil().getMetadataConnection().updateMetadata(collect);
}
```

Method updateMetadata(List) which generated by wsdl version 39.0 and 46.0

```
/**
 * Updates metadata entries synchronously.
 */
@WebMethod
@RequestWrapper(localName = "updateMetadata", targetNamespace = "http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata", className = "com.sforce.soap._2006._04.metadata.UpdateMetadata")
@ResponseWrapper(localName = "updateMetadataResponse", targetNamespace = "http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata", className = "com.sforce.soap._2006._04.metadata.UpdateMetadataResponse")
@WebResult(name = "result", targetNamespace = "http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata")
public java.util.List<com.sforce.soap._2006._04.metadata.SaveResult> updateMetadata(
    @WebParam(name = "metadata", targetNamespace = "http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata")
    java.util.List<com.sforce.soap._2006._04.metadata.Metadata> metadata
);
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

thanks, Marian

Comment: r u updating customField metadata by which profile User? is that profile is API enabled in your scratch org?

Comment: User has profile : System Administrator; And yes it is enabled.